# If $\int_x^{x+T}f(t)dt=C$ then $f$ is periodic

Tags: integration, functions, periodic-functions

> If $f$ is a continious function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and
>   there exists $C$ such that:
>
> $\forall x\in\mathbb{R} :\int_x^{x+T}f(t)dt=C$
>
> then $f$ is $T$-periodic.

Proving the inverse is easier and has already been answer on another question.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Differentiate both sides of the equation $F(x)=\int_x^{x+T}f(t)\,dt=C$ with respect to $x$.  What can you immediately conclude?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Please feel free to upvote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)